# java script english to arabic and other languages conversion

Tags: javascript, translation

I m building a web project in jquery being used in client side and jsp/servlets at server end,i have a text area in which user writes and that written text is displayed in chat box text area.now i want to suport multiple languages in it.Earlier i was using only english.Now i want that if user writes in english it should be displayed in arabic in chat box area.What ever language user selects arabic,french,german,latin from a drop down the text  shold be converted in that particular language.Presently i need to implement arabic first then later on other languages.Plz help

Comment: Just wondering why are using jquery tag for your question? And not sure I can understand what are you asking here?

Comment: If you could show us your chat application we could tell you exactly where things go bad... and the solution.

Comment: This is not a small project you're talking about - even large corporations like Google don't have translator software working particularly well.

Comment: Are you writing this in Java or JavaScript?  Having the two tags 'java' and 'script' is confusing, particularly when you have a Java back-end and a jQuery front-end.

Answer (score 2):

Erm.  What I would recommend, rather than all this drop-down-selecting business, is simply making your chat application's presentation-layer and persistence-layer encoding [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), which supports your users inputting whatever locally appropriate characters they like.

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, you want a translation from English to other languages. So you might want to take a look at the [Google translation API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/). It is quite usable and accurate.

Comment: Thanks flokra ,actually i dont want traslator ,i wnt if sumbody writes in english hii,it shold be converted in arabic or german as hii in their language.

Comment: that's what a translator does or am I missing something?